# Finding angle of a spigot that produces a parabolic fountain of water

Tags: integration, conic-sections

I am currently doing a math exploration and I need help in determining how to find the angle of a spigot that would maximize the area under a parabolic fountain. I thought of this topic to investigate, but I have no idea how to start! I know that this somehow involves integration.

I have trouble trying to find the angle and relating that to the water being ejected from the spigot.

Comment: Does your parabola ends at the same horizontal level??

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the spigot is at ground height, so that the parabolic trajectory of the water is given by the parameterization
$$
x(t) = (v_0\cos \theta )\\
y(t) = (v_0 \sin \theta)t -gt^2
$$
Solving for $t$ in terms of $x$ gives 
$$
t = \frac{x}{v_0 \cos\theta} \implies\\
y(x) = -\left(\frac{g}{v_0^2 \cos^2\theta}\right)x^2 + (\tan \theta) x
$$ 
Now, find the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the area beneath this curve.

Comment: thank you for the reply!! how did you get the parabolic trajectory of water? How was it determined? Does V stand for velocity? Sorry if these questions seem ignorant, but my level of mathematics is only 1st year uni ><

Comment: This is the standard sort of thing covered in physics; if this isn't a physics course, then presumably something like $y(x)$ or the parameterization was provided to you in some form.  $v_0$ stands for the velocity of the water as it exits the spigot.

Comment: Ah, you said that this was your choice for math exploration... sorry about that. I'll see if I can find a source.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find [this](https://www.boundless.com/physics/textbooks/boundless-physics-textbook/two-dimensional-kinematics-3/projectile-motion-42/basic-equations-and-parabolic-path-226-10952/) helpful.  Keep in mind that, in this analysis, we ignore any effects of air-resistance.

Comment: thank you so much! I have not taken any physics courses since 10th grade lol...